# Java systemtray menu only shows when run from eclipse. Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

So what's the question?

**I am running Mac OSX 10.8.5, and am trying to deploy a java application. Throughout testing i would run from right clicking and selecting run as java application, however now when i export it as a runnable jar, the system tray menu does not show up.**

What is some troubleshooting i can do?

The following is the code used to present the menu in the system tray:

```
public class TrayMenu {
    private static Image iconImage;
    private static SystemTray sysTray;
    private static PopupMenu menu;
    private static MenuItem item0;
    private static TrayIcon trayIcon;

    public static void loadTrayIcon() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tray Frame");

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3)); 

        if (SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            sysTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

            iconImage  = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("osx_tray_icon.png");

            menu = new PopupMenu();

            item0 = new MenuItem("TestApp v0.1");

            menu.add(item0);

            trayIcon = new TrayIcon(iconImage, "TestApp", menu);

            try {
                sysTray.add(trayIcon);
            } catch(AWTException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly when I run the project as so:

[image]

However when i export the project as a Runnable Jar, Mac OSX Bundle, or simply a Jar and attempt to run trough Terminal, the system tray menu does not show up during run time. Why?

Comment: The problem was with the image not being included into the classpath :) and was not included in the export.